# Starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown

Tags: bash, shell, docker, dockerfile

I want to understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT works. So, I just created a very simple `Dockerfile`

```
FROM scratch

CMD echo "Hello First"

ENTRYPOINT echo "Hello second"
```

Then I build image of this :

```
docker build -t my_image .
```

The logs are as below:

> Step 1/3 : FROM scratch  ---> Step 2/3 : CMD echo "Hello First"  --->
>   Using cache  ---> 9f2b6a00982f Step 3/3 : ENTRYPOINT echo "Hello
>   second"  ---> Using cache  ---> 1bbe520f9526 Successfully built
>   1bbe520f9526 Successfully tagged my_image:latest SECURITY WARNING: You
>   are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker
>   host. All files and directories added to build context w ill have
>   '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset
>   permissions for sensitive files and directories.

When I create a container of this image it returns:

```
docker run my_image
```

Error is:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"/bin/sh\": stat /b in/sh: no such file or directory": unknown.

Can someone please help me about error?

Comment: refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21553353/9025542

Comment: I wanted to [edit] your question to fix the formatting of the Docker build transcript and the error message, but I could not guess what they really looked like. Please use code formatting for computer messages or at the very least don't rewrap them.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are two things happening here.

A Dockerfile that starts `FROM scratch` starts from a base image that has absolutely nothing at all in it.  It is totally empty.  There is not a set of base tools or libraries or anything else, beyond a couple of device files Docker pushes in for you.

The `ENTRYPOINT echo ...` command gets rewritten by Docker into `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo ..."]`, and causes the `CMD` to be totally ignored.  Unless overridden with `docker run --entrypoint`, this becomes the main process the container runs.

Since it is a `FROM scratch` image and contains absolutely nothing at all, it doesn't contain a shell, hence the "/bin/sh: no such file or directory" error.

Comment: How can I install sh into the image?

Comment: Building images `FROM scratch` is kind of an advanced topic.  `FROM ubuntu:18.04` might give you a more familiar environment.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, when launching `boot2docker.iso` in a Linux virtual machine running in Virtualbox, `/bin/sh` is there or rather its implementation by `busybox`. How is `FROM scratch` different from starting a released `boot2docker.iso`?

Comment: Boot2Docker is a virtual machine, not a Docker image.  Also there is _nothing_ in `FROM scratch`.  Actually nothing.  No Busybox.  If you need a `/bin/sh` (99%, but not 100%, of images do) there is a [`busybox`](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox/) image that has it, but usually people start with [`alpine`](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/) which can run most compiled programs and is easier to extend.

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you. Is it a reasonable assumption that running boot2docker.iso in a Virtualbox yields the same execution environment (for a program or script) as doing `FROM docker` and then launching a script with `RUN`?

Comment: No, they'll be quite different (both in terms of filesystem and other processes running).