# tar -xvf failing in dockerfile

Tags: docker

I want to create my own Docker image using the following Dockerfile

```
FROM scratch
COPY apache-cassandra-3.11.6-bin.tar.gz .
RUN tar -xzf apache-cassandra-3.11.6-bin.tar.gz
```

When I run the command, the tar instruction fails. Why? I am on Windows 10.

```
C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\cassandra_image_test>docker build -f CassandraImageDockerFile.txt -t manucassandra .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  184.8MB
Step 1/3 : FROM scratch
 --->
Step 2/3 : COPY apache-cassandra-3.11.6-bin.tar.gz .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> deda426d6948
Step 3/3 : RUN tar -xzf apache-cassandra-3.11.6-bin.tar.gz .
 ---> Running in 3edfb1031c06
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Could it be that because I am not using an existing image, `tar` is not present in the image and thus `tar` is failing?

Comment: Looks like already answered question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820846/starting-container-process-caused-exec-bin-sh-stat-bin-sh-no-such-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820846/starting-container-process-caused-exec-bin-sh-stat-bin-sh-no-such-file)

Answer (score 2):

```
stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory
```

You started from a `scratch` image that has *nothing*. Then you told Docker to `RUN` a command, but you have no shell.

So you can't run *any* command, much less `tar`.

Why not start with `alpine`?

Comment: Thanks. changed scratch to ubuntu and that has moved things forward. Now to next challenge of making an image.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, whatever base image "scratch" is, it doesn't have `/bin/sh`, let alone `tar` or anything else. I would consider starting from a known OS image, or even the Cassandra official image on DockerHub. https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra

Answer (score 0):

A Dockerfile that starts FROM scratch starts from a base image that has absolutely nothing at all in it. It is totally empty. There is not a set of base tools or libraries or anything else.