# Docker from scratch CMD bug

Tags: docker, caddy

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM golang as builder
ARG CADDY_HASH=4b4e99bdb2e327d553a5f773f827f624181714af
WORKDIR /root/caddy
RUN wget -qO- github.com/caddyserver/caddy/archive/"$CADDY_HASH".tar.gz | tar zx --strip-components=1
RUN set -e; cd cmd/caddy && CGO_ENABLED=0 go build

FROM scratch

COPY --from=builder /root/caddy/cmd/caddy/caddy /

ARG PORT=8000
ENV PORT $PORT
EXPOSE $PORT

CMD /caddy file-server --browse --listen :$PORT
```

I build and run with this command

`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build -t caddy-static-docker:latest . && docker run -e PORT=8000 -p 8000:8000 caddy-static-docker:latest`

Why this won't work and I receive this error?

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown.

Comment: Also see [Starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820846/starting-container-process-caused-exec-bin-sh-stat-bin-sh-no-such-file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an entrypoint instead of CMD

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/caddy"]
CMD ["file-server", "--browse", "--listen", "8080"]
```

Also note the json syntax (exec form), which leads to the things not run in a subshell.

> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment variable expansion, not docker.

source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

> The shell form prevents any CMD or run command line arguments from being used, but has the disadvantage that your ENTRYPOINT will be started as a subcommand of /bin/sh -c, which does not pass signals. This means that the executable will not be the container’s PID 1 - and will not receive Unix signals - so your executable will not receive a SIGTERM from docker stop .

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Your PORT will still cause issues. Consider hard coding it.

Comment: I can not use hardcoded PORT on Cloud Run, it is dynamic

Comment: @Rodrigo, I would assume that the port outside, is dynamic. The published port like `--publish <my-dynamic-port>:8080`. But the port of your app doesnt have to be dynamic.

Comment: Same error [ERROR] '/bin/sh' is not a recognized subcommand; see 'caddy help'

Comment: @Rodrigo, its not the same error, it already used caddy properly as entrypoint. Otherwise, you would not get *see caddy help*.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `alpine` image which is a lightweight image to run shell commands and it has `/bin/sh` loaded in it.


The SCRATCH image is basically empty with nothing inside `/` folder, thus no executables to execute anything that is given as part of CMD.